# nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named lo

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I am using nginx to upstream to a different set of servers depending on the geo of the user. As it seems the geoip module does not return any value for the local addresses (localhost, 192.168.0.X ... etc).
https://www.maxmind.com/en/faq

I am trying ot handle this as follow :
1) check if the current ip is a local ip :

```
    geo $isLanIP {
     default no;
     192.168.0.0/24 yes;
     127.0.0.1 yes;
    }
```

2) depending on the value of **isLanIP** proxy_pass a different upstream :

```
    if ($isLanIP ~ no){
     proxy_pass http://$geoip_country_code.SearchControllerUpStream/;
     break;
    }

    if ($isLanIP ~ yes){
     proxy_pass http://local.SearchControllerUpStream/;
     break;
    }
```

when starting nginx, the error '"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named lo. ... .conf:64' is raised. 
L64 is second proxy_pass call.

BR.

server block :

```
  server { 
    listen       8080;
    server_name  host;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    error_page 404 = 404.html;
    error_page 403 = 403.html;
    root /home/user/app;

    location /SearchController {
        proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";

    if ($isLanIP ~ no){
        proxy_pass http://$geoip_country_code.SearchControllerUpStream/;
        break;
    }

    if ($isLanIP ~ yes){
        proxy_pass http://local.SearchControllerUpStream/;
        break;
    }

    limit_except POST {
            deny all;    
        }
    }

    location / {
    include emergingthreats-deny.conf;
    include projecthoneypot-deny.conf;
    include spamhaus-deny.conf;
    index index.htm index.html;
    }
 }
```

Comment: really no one can help ?